# Workmanager injection causing illegalState exception

Tags: android-workmanager

I have recently our app where workManager is being provided by @Provides annotation

```
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideWorkManager(@ForApplication context: Context): WorkManager {
        return WorkManager.getInstance(context)
    }
```

Out of 800K installs very small subset of users, google play is reporting following error, has anyone seen something similar.

I am using dagger version 2.38.1 and workManager version 2.3.4

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication (ActivityThread.java:6998)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300 (ActivityThread.java:270)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:2051)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:107)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:237)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7948)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:493)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1075)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
  at androidx.work.impl.WorkManagerImpl.getInstance (SourceFile:156)
  at androidx.work.WorkManager.getInstance (SourceFile:184)
  at com.microsoft.yammer.domain.injection.CoreDomainModule.provideWorkManager (SourceFile:170)
  at com.microsoft.yammer.domain.injection.CoreDomainModule_ProvideWorkManagerFactory.provideWorkManager (SourceFile:38)java.lang.RuntimeException: 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication (ActivityThread.java:6998)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300 (ActivityThread.java:270)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:2051)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:107)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:237)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7948)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:493)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1075)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
  at androidx.work.impl.WorkManagerImpl.getInstance (SourceFile:156)
  at androidx.work.WorkManager.getInstance (SourceFile:184)
  at XXX.XYZModule.provideWorkManager (SourceFile:170)
  at XXX.XYZModule_ProvideWorkManagerFactory.provideWorkManager (SourceFile:38)
```

Comment: I see this warning in very old 1.0.0-alpha11 change set https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/work#1.0.0-alpha11 ```Attempting to initialize WorkManager more than once per process will now result in an IllegalStateException. This is a breaking change.```

Answer (score 3):

I don't have enough reputation to leave a comment but wanted to share some stackoverflow answers that I've found in regards to some phones killing the background tasks.

[WorkManager is not working as intended in devices and some emulators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60584989/workmanager-is-not-working-as-intended-in-devices-and-some-emulators)

[Android Work Manager is not working in my oppo phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65677676/android-work-manager-is-not-working-in-my-oppo-phone)

Not sure whether you've come across these answers but it may be the cause of your errors as you've mentioned that the app is working on most phones.